# Sending Multicast with RAW Socket in C on Linux

Tags: c, unix, multicast, raw-sockets

I have written a programm running on Ubuntu LTE that should send an Multicast-Message to 239.255.25.25 Port 5004 using a raw socket. To receive the Multicast, I am using an UDP Socket. The data to send via the socket was captured with wireshark from an rtp stream. The Problem is now, that I am not able to receive the Message with an UDP Socket. 
For checking if the receiver is correct, I had built an Sender, which is using an normal UDP Socket.
When I am now sending the same message via RAW and UDP Socket,  i am only able to receive the message sent from the udp socket.

I am using wireshark for analyzing the packages, the multicast package from the raw socket and the multicast package from the udp socket seem to be the same, but why is it not possible to receive the package sent from the raw socket?

Code from the UDP and RAW Socket Sender:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<features.h>
#include<net/if.h>
#include<linux/if_packet.h>
#include<linux/if_ether.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<net/ethernet.h>
#include<net/if_arp.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>

#define DEVICE "eth0"


int rawsock;
struct sockaddr_ll sll;
struct ifreq ifr;


unsigned char dataArray[]={0x01, 0x00, 0x5e, 0x7f, 0x19, 0x19, 0x00, 0x0a, 0x5e, 0x56, 0xed, 0x87, 0x08, 0x00, 0x45, 0x00, 0x05, 0x4c, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x01, 0x11, 0xa9, 0xdc, 0xc0, 0xa8, 0x01, 0x04, 0xef, 0xff, 0x19, 0x19, 0x80, 0xda, 0x13, 0x8c, 0x05, 0x38, 0xd0, 0x0e, 0x80, 0xa1, 0xb0, 0x14, 0x9a, 0x7d, 0x01, 0x56, 0xb2, 0x50, 0x00, 0x98, 0x47, 0x40, 0x45, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x06, 0x2b, 0x80, 0xc0, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x0e, 0xbd, 0x15, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x2c, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x05, 0x11, 0x03, 0x87, 0xf4, 0x4e, 0xcd, 0x0a, 0x4b, 0xdc, 0xa1, 0x94, 0x3a, 0xc3, 0xd4, 0x9b, 0x17, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0xa8, 0xc3, 0x60, 0x3a, 0x81, 0xb5, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xe0, 0xda, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x47, 0x00, 0x44, 0x17, 0xb2, 0x04, 0x6e, 0xb5, 0x36, 0x0d, 0x33, 0x4b, 0x52, 0x6b, 0xcf, 0x87, 0x9b, 0xb2, 0xd9, 0xba, 0xda, 0x94, 0x64, 0xe5, 0x46, 0x58, 0x4c, 0x15, 0x3b, 0x17, 0x31, 0xc4, 0xea, 0x5c, 0x10, 0x89, 0xbe, 0x24, 0x10, 0x84, 0x0a, 0xfc, 0x75, 0x02, 0x54, 0xab, 0xa1, 0x29, 0x00, 0xa8, 0xa8, 0x56, 0x6f, 0x02, 0x54, 0xa9, 0xcc, 0xb4, 0x04, 0xea, 0xb2, 0xbe, 0x10, 0x8d, 0x6c, 0xa0, 0xc2, 0x80, 0x5d, 0x25, 0xe9, 0x5f, 0x0b, 0x09, 0x2c, 0x6b, 0xe7, 0xbc, 0x2f, 0x75, 0x89, 0xea, 0x98, 0xb6, 0xea, 0x0e, 0x2a, 0x1c, 0x12, 0xa9, 0x1d, 0x28, 0x81, 0x3e, 0x5e, 0x2b, 0x33, 0xee, 0xdb, 0x3d, 0x36, 0xd1, 0x57, 0xee, 0x85, 0x35, 0x28, 0x68, 0xfd, 0xd4, 0x71, 0xd8, 0xd7, 0xd5, 0x74, 0x6f, 0xbf, 0xbd, 0xfc, 0xe0, 0x5e, 0x52, 0x04, 0xe3, 0xc5, 0xbb, 0x08, 0x8f, 0xb3, 0x0d, 0xbc, 0x6a, 0x9c, 0x06, 0xe1, 0xb1, 0x67, 0xec, 0xba, 0xfc, 0xaf, 0x75, 0xc8, 0x84, 0x02, 0xa0, 0x6b, 0x08, 0x6d, 0x48, 0xb6, 0x8d, 0xef, 0x14, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0xd0, 0xea, 0x21, 0x94, 0xa8, 0x90, 0xe8, 0x00, 0x9b, 0xb4, 0x71, 0xa1, 0xce, 0x09, 0x04, 0x59, 0x18, 0x8c, 0x5a, 0x88, 0x5a, 0x2f, 0xa0, 0x2d, 0x91, 0xe2, 0x5a, 0xd8, 0x55, 0xe2, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x10, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xa3, 0x0d, 0x80, 0xea, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0x06, 0xd5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x11, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x76, 0x0d, 0xaa, 0x99, 0x03, 0x5a, 0xb1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xf4, 0x28, 0xc3, 0x60, 0x3a, 0xb5, 0x63, 0x9e, 0xc7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0xda, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf5, 0xf4, 0x12, 0x4d, 0x34, 0xe7, 0xaf, 0xa4, 0x82, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x63, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b};
unsigned char dataArray2[]={0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf5, 0xfd, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xd5, 0x8e, 0x7b, 0x47, 0x00, 0x44, 0x38, 0x88, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xbc, 0x0e, 0x64, 0xb2, 0x4c, 0x11, 0xe8, 0x39, 0x16, 0x93, 0x5a, 0x74, 0x0d, 0x1c, 0xf6, 0x2b, 0x55, 0x50, 0x14, 0xe5, 0x81, 0xac, 0xe4, 0xf3, 0x02, 0xa4, 0x50, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x4e, 0x37, 0x79, 0x4c, 0x01, 0x13, 0xc5, 0x8c, 0x6f, 0x9b, 0x43, 0x03, 0xe1, 0x82, 0xb2, 0x27, 0x2a, 0xf0, 0x47, 0x40, 0x44, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x90, 0x80, 0x80, 0x05, 0x25, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x34, 0xe3, 0xff, 0xf1, 0x4c, 0x80, 0x31, 0x1f, 0xfc, 0x21, 0x0a, 0xd4, 0x13, 0x7c, 0x88, 0x21, 0x08, 0x15, 0xfa, 0xdd, 0xdd, 0x45, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x95, 0x56, 0x02, 0x51, 0x02, 0xb3, 0x39, 0x00, 0x11, 0x06, 0x02, 0xc7, 0xda, 0x4d, 0xad, 0x5f, 0x84, 0xe7, 0x22, 0x5a, 0xb7, 0xca, 0x27, 0x7a, 0xb5, 0x09, 0xd8, 0x83, 0x73, 0x07, 0x6b, 0xb0, 0x34, 0x11, 0x02, 0x18, 0x9d, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x44, 0x73, 0x9b, 0x55, 0xc0, 0x8a, 0x00, 0x77, 0x2b, 0x84, 0xb7, 0x25, 0xc2, 0xa9, 0x43, 0x68, 0x85, 0x67, 0xa4, 0x69, 0xc6, 0x1e, 0x45, 0x75, 0x46, 0xbe, 0x4b, 0x32, 0x2b, 0xef, 0xba, 0x14, 0xd5, 0xc8, 0xb7, 0x97, 0x5a, 0xa4, 0x95, 0x4e, 0xf7, 0x25, 0xf0, 0x96, 0x05, 0xc1, 0x48, 0x32, 0x85, 0x2f, 0x0c, 0x30, 0x57, 0xb3, 0xac, 0x39, 0x19, 0x01, 0x95, 0x52, 0x0d, 0x07, 0x10, 0xf0, 0x46, 0xa8, 0xb4, 0xe8, 0x2b, 0xab, 0xad, 0x73, 0x2d, 0xf9, 0x4c, 0xc8, 0x31, 0x4a, 0xde, 0x7b, 0x01, 0x11, 0x21, 0x7c, 0x29, 0x4f, 0x01, 0x17, 0x17, 0xca, 0x9f, 0x04, 0x6b, 0x37, 0x59, 0x8e, 0x31, 0xbe, 0xba, 0x0d, 0xe9, 0x8b, 0x8d, 0xa5, 0x6a, 0xad, 0x50, 0x60, 0x96, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x12, 0x1f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xfb, 0x4d, 0x67, 0xb1, 0xfa, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x9e, 0xbe, 0x82, 0x49, 0xa6, 0x9c, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3f, 0x49, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xf6, 0x9a, 0x53, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0x41, 0x34, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0x1f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xfb, 0x4d, 0x67, 0xb1, 0xfa, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x9e, 0xbe, 0x82, 0x49, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0xda, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xa5, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x63, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea};

unsigned char dataComp[1370];



//UDP Socket Variablen


struct in_addr localInterface;
struct sockaddr_in groupSock;
int udpSock;
char groupAddress[]="239.255.25.25";
int groupPort = 5004;






unsigned char payloadOnly[]={0x80, 0xa1, 0xb0, 0x14, 0x9a, 0x7d, 0x01, 0x56, 0xb2, 0x50, 0x00, 0x98, 0x47, 0x40, 0x45, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xe0, 0x06, 0x2b, 0x80, 0xc0, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x0e, 0xbd, 0x15, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x2c, 0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x06, 0x05, 0x11, 0x03, 0x87, 0xf4, 0x4e, 0xcd, 0x0a, 0x4b, 0xdc, 0xa1, 0x94, 0x3a, 0xc3, 0xd4, 0x9b, 0x17, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0xa8, 0xc3, 0x60, 0x3a, 0x81, 0xb5, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xfa, 0xbf, 0x57, 0xea, 0xfd, 0x5f, 0xab, 0xf5, 0x7e, 0xaf, 0xd5, 0xe0, 0xda, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x47, 0x00, 0x44, 0x17, 0xb2, 0x04, 0x6e, 0xb5, 0x36, 0x0d, 0x33, 0x4b, 0x52, 0x6b, 0xcf, 0x87, 0x9b, 0xb2, 0xd9, 0xba, 0xda, 0x94, 0x64, 0xe5, 0x46, 0x58, 0x4c, 0x15, 0x3b, 0x17, 0x31, 0xc4, 0xea, 0x5c, 0x10, 0x89, 0xbe, 0x24, 0x10, 0x84, 0x0a, 0xfc, 0x75, 0x02, 0x54, 0xab, 0xa1, 0x29, 0x00, 0xa8, 0xa8, 0x56, 0x6f, 0x02, 0x54, 0xa9, 0xcc, 0xb4, 0x04, 0xea, 0xb2, 0xbe, 0x10, 0x8d, 0x6c, 0xa0, 0xc2, 0x80, 0x5d, 0x25, 0xe9, 0x5f, 0x0b, 0x09, 0x2c, 0x6b, 0xe7, 0xbc, 0x2f, 0x75, 0x89, 0xea, 0x98, 0xb6, 0xea, 0x0e, 0x2a, 0x1c, 0x12, 0xa9, 0x1d, 0x28, 0x81, 0x3e, 0x5e, 0x2b, 0x33, 0xee, 0xdb, 0x3d, 0x36, 0xd1, 0x57, 0xee, 0x85, 0x35, 0x28, 0x68, 0xfd, 0xd4, 0x71, 0xd8, 0xd7, 0xd5, 0x74, 0x6f, 0xbf, 0xbd, 0xfc, 0xe0, 0x5e, 0x52, 0x04, 0xe3, 0xc5, 0xbb, 0x08, 0x8f, 0xb3, 0x0d, 0xbc, 0x6a, 0x9c, 0x06, 0xe1, 0xb1, 0x67, 0xec, 0xba, 0xfc, 0xaf, 0x75, 0xc8, 0x84, 0x02, 0xa0, 0x6b, 0x08, 0x6d, 0x48, 0xb6, 0x8d, 0xef, 0x14, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0xd0, 0xea, 0x21, 0x94, 0xa8, 0x90, 0xe8, 0x00, 0x9b, 0xb4, 0x71, 0xa1, 0xce, 0x09, 0x04, 0x59, 0x18, 0x8c, 0x5a, 0x88, 0x5a, 0x2f, 0xa0, 0x2d, 0x91, 0xe2, 0x5a, 0xd8, 0x55, 0xe2, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x10, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0x96, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd6, 0xa9, 0xd4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xe8, 0xa3, 0x0d, 0x80, 0xea, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0xd5, 0x3a, 0x06, 0xd5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x11, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x77, 0xaa, 0x3b, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0xea, 0x8e, 0xf5, 0x47, 0x7a, 0xa3, 0xbd, 0x51, 0xde, 0xa8, 0xef, 0x54, 0x76, 0x0d, 0xaa, 0x99, 0x03, 0x5a, 0xb1, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xf4, 0x28, 0xc3, 0x60, 0x3a, 0xb5, 0x63, 0x9e, 0xc7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0xda, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf5, 0xf4, 0x12, 0x4d, 0x34, 0xe7, 0xaf, 0xa4, 0x82, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x63, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b};
unsigned char payloadOnly2[]={0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf5, 0xfd, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xd5, 0x8e, 0x7b, 0x47, 0x00, 0x44, 0x38, 0x88, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xbc, 0x0e, 0x64, 0xb2, 0x4c, 0x11, 0xe8, 0x39, 0x16, 0x93, 0x5a, 0x74, 0x0d, 0x1c, 0xf6, 0x2b, 0x55, 0x50, 0x14, 0xe5, 0x81, 0xac, 0xe4, 0xf3, 0x02, 0xa4, 0x50, 0x05, 0x9a, 0x4e, 0x37, 0x79, 0x4c, 0x01, 0x13, 0xc5, 0x8c, 0x6f, 0x9b, 0x43, 0x03, 0xe1, 0x82, 0xb2, 0x27, 0x2a, 0xf0, 0x47, 0x40, 0x44, 0x19, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xc0, 0x01, 0x90, 0x80, 0x80, 0x05, 0x25, 0x69, 0xf3, 0x34, 0xe3, 0xff, 0xf1, 0x4c, 0x80, 0x31, 0x1f, 0xfc, 0x21, 0x0a, 0xd4, 0x13, 0x7c, 0x88, 0x21, 0x08, 0x15, 0xfa, 0xdd, 0xdd, 0x45, 0x25, 0x4a, 0x95, 0x56, 0x02, 0x51, 0x02, 0xb3, 0x39, 0x00, 0x11, 0x06, 0x02, 0xc7, 0xda, 0x4d, 0xad, 0x5f, 0x84, 0xe7, 0x22, 0x5a, 0xb7, 0xca, 0x27, 0x7a, 0xb5, 0x09, 0xd8, 0x83, 0x73, 0x07, 0x6b, 0xb0, 0x34, 0x11, 0x02, 0x18, 0x9d, 0xf5, 0xda, 0x44, 0x73, 0x9b, 0x55, 0xc0, 0x8a, 0x00, 0x77, 0x2b, 0x84, 0xb7, 0x25, 0xc2, 0xa9, 0x43, 0x68, 0x85, 0x67, 0xa4, 0x69, 0xc6, 0x1e, 0x45, 0x75, 0x46, 0xbe, 0x4b, 0x32, 0x2b, 0xef, 0xba, 0x14, 0xd5, 0xc8, 0xb7, 0x97, 0x5a, 0xa4, 0x95, 0x4e, 0xf7, 0x25, 0xf0, 0x96, 0x05, 0xc1, 0x48, 0x32, 0x85, 0x2f, 0x0c, 0x30, 0x57, 0xb3, 0xac, 0x39, 0x19, 0x01, 0x95, 0x52, 0x0d, 0x07, 0x10, 0xf0, 0x46, 0xa8, 0xb4, 0xe8, 0x2b, 0xab, 0xad, 0x73, 0x2d, 0xf9, 0x4c, 0xc8, 0x31, 0x4a, 0xde, 0x7b, 0x01, 0x11, 0x21, 0x7c, 0x29, 0x4f, 0x01, 0x17, 0x17, 0xca, 0x9f, 0x04, 0x6b, 0x37, 0x59, 0x8e, 0x31, 0xbe, 0xba, 0x0d, 0xe9, 0x8b, 0x8d, 0xa5, 0x6a, 0xad, 0x50, 0x60, 0x96, 0x47, 0x00, 0x45, 0x12, 0x1f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xfb, 0x4d, 0x67, 0xb1, 0xfa, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x9e, 0xbe, 0x82, 0x49, 0xa6, 0x9c, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfa, 0x56, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3f, 0x49, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xf6, 0x9a, 0x53, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0x41, 0x34, 0xd6, 0x7b, 0x1f, 0x4a, 0xd3, 0x59, 0xeb, 0xfb, 0x4d, 0x67, 0xb1, 0xfa, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x9e, 0xbe, 0x82, 0x49, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd8, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x5f, 0xda, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x8f, 0xa5, 0x69, 0xac, 0xf6, 0x3e, 0x95, 0xa6, 0xb3, 0xd7, 0xd2, 0xb4, 0xd6, 0x7a, 0xfd, 0x26, 0x9a, 0xcf, 0x63, 0xf4, 0x9a, 0x6b, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea, 0x8e, 0x9d, 0x51, 0xd3, 0xaa, 0x3a, 0x75, 0x47, 0x4e, 0xa8, 0xe9, 0xd5, 0x1d, 0x3a, 0xa3, 0xa7, 0x54, 0x74, 0xea};

unsigned char payloadComp[1328];



int main()
{

    do{

    memmove(dataComp, dataArray,sizeof(dataArray));
    memmove(&dataComp[sizeof(dataArray)],dataArray2,(sizeof(dataArray2)));

    printf("Press Enter for Sending Multicast via RAW Socket...\n");
    getchar();

    //RAW Socket


    if ((rawsock = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL)))== -1)
    {
        perror("Error creating raw socket: ");
        exit(-1);
    }

    bzero(&sll, sizeof(sll));
    bzero(&ifr, sizeof(ifr));


    strncpy((char *)ifr.ifr_name, DEVICE, IFNAMSIZ);
    if ((ioctl(rawsock, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr)) == -1)
    {
        printf("Error getting Interface index !\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


    sll.sll_family = AF_PACKET;
    sll.sll_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;


    if(sendto(rawsock, dataComp, 1370, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sll, sizeof(sll)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Sending datagram message error");
    }


 //UDP Socket
    printf("For Sending Multicast via UDP Socket press Enter \n");
    getchar();

    memmove(payloadComp, payloadOnly, sizeof(payloadOnly));
    memmove(&payloadComp[sizeof(payloadOnly)],payloadOnly2,(sizeof(payloadOnly)));

    udpSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(udpSock < 0)
    {
      perror("Opening datagram socket error");
      return 0;
    }
    else

    memset((char *) &groupSock, 0, sizeof(groupSock));
    groupSock.sin_family = AF_INET;
    groupSock.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(groupAddress); //Multicast Adress
    groupSock.sin_port = htons(groupPort);                 //Port for Multicast
    localInterface.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.4");
    if(setsockopt(udpSock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char *)&localInterface, sizeof(localInterface)) < 0)
    {
      perror("Setting local interface error");
      return 0;
    }
    else


    if(sendto(udpSock, payloadComp, 1328, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&groupSock, sizeof(groupSock)) < 0)
    {
        perror("Sending datagram message error");
    }



    }while(1);


    return 0;
}
```

Code from the UDP Receiver:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#define SOCKET_ERROR        -1
#define BUFFER_SIZE         100
#define PACKETLENGTH        1328


struct sockaddr_in localSock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int sd;
int datalen;
char databuf[PACKETLENGTH];
int i=0;
char addressGroup[]="239.255.25.25";
int groupPort = 5004;





int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{


//Begin Code Multicast UDP
//*************************************************

/* Create a datagram socket on which to receive. */

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

if(sd < 0)

{

perror("Opening datagram socket error");

exit(1);

}

else

printf("Opening datagram socket for UDP....OK.\n");



/* Enable SO_REUSEADDR to allow multiple instances of this */

/* application to receive copies of the multicast datagrams. */

{

int reuse = 1;

if(setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)

{

perror("Setting SO_REUSEADDR error");

close(sd);

exit(1);

}

else

printf("Setting SO_REUSEADDR...OK.\n");

}

memset((char *) &localSock, 0, sizeof(localSock));

localSock.sin_family = AF_INET;

localSock.sin_port = htons(groupPort);

localSock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if(bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&localSock, sizeof(localSock)))

{

perror("Binding datagram socket error");

close(sd);

exit(1);

}

else

printf("Binding UDP datagram socket...OK.\n");



group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(addressGroup);

group.imr_interface.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;


if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group)) < 0)

{

perror("Adding multicast group error");

close(sd);

exit(1);

}

else

printf("Adding multicast group...OK.\n");
printf("Now Receiving Packages from %s Multicast Group\n",&addressGroup);

do{

datalen = sizeof(databuf);

if(read(sd, databuf, datalen) < 0)

{

perror("Reading datagram message error");

close(sd);

exit(1);

}

else

{

printf("Reading UDP datagram message...OK.\n");

printf("The UDP message from multicast server is: \"%s\"\n", databuf);

memset(databuf,0,datalen);

i++;
}
}while(i<=9999);


close(sd);
return 0;

}
```

Maybe it is an fault in the HAL, because when i'm receiving the two packages with wireshark, it seems that the are identical, but the udp socket had found a difference between both of them.
But I would be glad if it is an programming fault from me. :-)
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`tcpdump -vvv` tells me `[bad udp cksum af7f!]`

Comment: Yeah, you are right! Thanks a lot! I have disabled the checksum (set the bytes to zero) and now it works! The mysterious thing is, that the checksum in the udp header of the datagram which i have send with the udp socket is also false, but i can receive it. It seems that the udp checksum only have to be correct if i am sending with a raw socket. Thank you very much!

Comment: @DonCarlos , if you see a wrong udp checksum in the packet sent through the regular udp socket, this could be caused due to udp checksum offloading. In that case, the NIC or the driver is computing the checksum before it goes out the wire but this is done after it is captured by tcpdump. If you capture the packet in the receiver host, you should see the checksum is correct (otherwise, the packet should be dropped). Raw sockets bypass most of the IP socket stack, so offloading may not be happening.