# No output when using raw socket to send spoofed packets via multicast to different subnet

Tags: c, sockets, multicast, packet, subnet

My application is a specialized user space UDP router that uses raw sockets to produce unicast and multicast output with actual or spoofed source addresses in the IP packet headers of the sent packets.

Briefly, there is one permutation of the outputs that fails to reach some of the destination hosts.

My question:  is there some subtle logic in the Linux stack that prevents certain routing permutations, or is the output function I am using missing something?

I can't create a UDP packet writer that successfully sends packets that (1) contain a spoofed source address, (2) to a multicast address, (3) if sending host is on subnet A, (4) receiving host is on subnet B, if the (valid) spoofed source address is on subnet A.

Subnet A = 10.200.xx.nn
Subnet B = 10.200.yy.nn

Source address in packet = sending host

```
                           Subnet                
Src addr = sender addr  A   A   B   B   
Receiver                A   B   A   B   
Result                  Yes Yes Yes Yes
```

Source address in packet != sending host

```
                                 Subnet                
Sender                  A   A   A   A   B   B   B   B    
Spoofed src addr        A   A   B   B   A   A   B   B
Receiver                A   B   A   B   A   B   A   B
Result                  Yes Yes Yes No  No  Yes Yes Yes
```

The spoof addresses are to existing network devices.

Wireshark run on the failing destinations shows no UDP data.

My raw socket class is derived very closely from the example program I found at Stack Overflow kindly donated by user Peter O. on March 11, 2012 - question 3737612 "Raw socket sendto failed using C on Linux".  I have appended my version of it, with a
couple of enhancements/fixes.  I compiled and ran it on RedHat 5, gcc 4.1.2.

I checked /etc/sysctl.conf entries that might be relevant, and set the following with no discernable effect:

```
  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth2.rp_filter=0
  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.lo.rp_filter=0
  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0

  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_source_route=1
  sudo /sbin/sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_source_route=1
```

My modified version of the example from 3737612 is appended.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <netinet/udp.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <time.h>

//The packet length in byes
#define PCKT_LEN 50

//Date size in bytes
#define DATA_SIZE 15

//PseudoHeader struct used to calculate UDP checksum.
typedef struct PseudoHeader{
    unsigned long int source_ip;
    unsigned long int dest_ip;
    unsigned char reserved;
    unsigned char protocol;
    unsigned short int udp_length;
}PseudoHeader;

// Ripped from Richard Stevans Book
unsigned short ComputeChecksum(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
    long sum = 0;  /* assume 32 bit long, 16 bit short */
    unsigned short *temp = (unsigned short *)data;

    while(len > 1){
    sum += *temp++;
    if(sum & 0x80000000)   /* if high order bit set, fold */
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
    len -= 2;
    }

    if(len)   /* take care of left over byte */
    sum += (unsigned short) *((unsigned char *)temp);

    while(sum>>16)
    sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

    return ~sum;
}

int BindRawSocketToInterface(int rawsock, char *addr, short int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in s_addr;
    s_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    s_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(addr);
    s_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    if((bind(rawsock, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, sizeof(s_addr)))== -1)
    {
    perror("Error binding raw socket to interface\n");
    exit(-1);
    }

    return 1;
}

// Fabricate the IP header or we can use the
// standard header structures but assign our own values.
struct ip *CreateIPHeader(char *srcip, char *destip)
{
    struct ip *ip_header;

    ip_header = (struct ip *)malloc(sizeof(struct ip));

    ip_header->ip_v = 4;
    ip_header->ip_hl = 5;
    ip_header->ip_tos = 0;
    ip_header->ip_len = htons(sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE);
    ip_header->ip_id = htons(111);
    ip_header->ip_off = 0;
    ip_header->ip_ttl = 111;
    ip_header->ip_p = IPPROTO_UDP;
    ip_header->ip_sum = 0; /* We will calculate the checksum later */
    inet_pton(AF_INET, srcip, &ip_header->ip_src);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, destip, &ip_header->ip_dst);

    /* Calculate the IP checksum now :
    The IP Checksum is only over the IP header */
    ip_header->ip_sum = ComputeChecksum((unsigned char *)ip_header, ip_header->ip_hl*4);

    return (ip_header);
}

// Creates a the UDP header.
struct udphdr *CreateUdpHeader(char *srcport, char *destport )
{
    struct udphdr *udp_header;

    /* Check netinet/udp.h for header definiation */

    udp_header = (struct udphdr *)malloc(sizeof(struct udphdr));

    udp_header->source = htons(atoi(srcport));
    udp_header->dest = htons(atoi(destport));
    udp_header->len = htons(sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE); //TODO: need to specify this
    udp_header->check = htons(0);

    return (udp_header);
}

void CreatePseudoHeaderAndComputeUdpChecksum(struct udphdr *udp_header, struct ip *ip_header, unsigned char *data)
{

    /*The TCP Checksum is calculated over the PseudoHeader + TCP header +Data*/

    /* Find the size of the TCP Header + Data */
    int segment_len = ntohs(ip_header->ip_len) - ip_header->ip_hl*4;

    /* Total length over which TCP checksum will be computed */
    int header_len = sizeof(PseudoHeader) + segment_len;

    /* Allocate the memory */

    unsigned char *hdr = (unsigned char *)malloc(header_len);

    /* Fill in the pseudo header first */

    PseudoHeader *pseudo_header = (PseudoHeader *)hdr;

    pseudo_header->source_ip = ip_header->ip_src.s_addr;
    pseudo_header->dest_ip = ip_header->ip_dst.s_addr;
    pseudo_header->reserved = 0;
    pseudo_header->protocol = ip_header->ip_p;
    pseudo_header->udp_length = htons(segment_len);


    /* Now copy TCP */

    memcpy((hdr + sizeof(PseudoHeader)), (void *)udp_header, 8);

    /* Now copy the Data */

    memcpy((hdr + sizeof(PseudoHeader) + 8), data, DATA_SIZE);

    /* Calculate the Checksum */

    udp_header->check = ComputeChecksum(hdr, header_len);

    /* Free the PseudoHeader */
    free(hdr);
}

// Source IP, source port, target IP, target port from the command line arguments
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sd, ix;
    char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
    char data[DATA_SIZE];
    int one = 1;
    char interface[100];
    struct ifreq ifr;
    time_t the_time;

    // Source and destination addresses: IP and port
    struct sockaddr_in to_addr;
    const int *val = &one;

    printf("IP Header Size: %u \n", sizeof(struct ip));
    printf("UDP Header Size: %u \n", sizeof(struct udphdr));
    printf("Data Size: %d\n", DATA_SIZE);
    printf("IP Total: %u \n", sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE);

    memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);

    if(argc != 5 && argc != 6)
    {
    printf("- Invalid parameters!!!\n");
    printf("- Usage %s <source hostname/IP> <source port> <target hostname/IP> <target port> [interface]\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
    }
    if (argc == 6)
      strcpy(interface, argv[5]);
    else
      strcpy(interface, "eth0");
    printf("Interface:  %s\n", interface);

    // bind() fails in BindRawSocketToInterface() above if it is passed a source address that
    // is not the actual host sending (i.e. spoofing):  "Cannot assign requested address"
    #if 0
    // Create a raw socket with UDP protocol
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
    perror("socket() error");
    exit(-1);
    }
    else
    printf("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and UDP protocol is OK.\n");

    //Bind the socket to the source address and port.
    BindRawSocketToInterface(sd, argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    #else
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
    perror("socket() error");
    exit(-1);
    }
    else
    printf("socket() - Using SOCK_RAW socket and RAW protocol is OK.\n");
    memset (&ifr, 0, sizeof (ifr));
    snprintf (ifr.ifr_name, sizeof (ifr.ifr_name), "%s", interface);
    if (ioctl(sd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr))
    {
    perror("ioctl() error ");
    exit(-1);
    }
    if (setsockopt (sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, &ifr, sizeof (ifr)) < 0)
    {
    perror("setsockopt() error (#2)");
    exit(-1);
    }
    #endif
    // Inform the kernel do not fill up the packet structure. we will build our own...
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
    perror("setsockopt() error");
    close(sd);
    exit(-1);
    }
    else
    printf("setsockopt() is OK.\n");

    // The source is redundant, may be used later if needed
    // The address family
    to_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    to_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[3]);
    to_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[4]));

    //Create the IP header.
    struct ip *ip_header = CreateIPHeader(argv[1], argv[3]);
    //Create the UDP header.
    struct udphdr *udp_header = CreateUdpHeader(argv[2], argv[4]);

    printf("Using raw socket and UDP protocol\n");
    printf("Using Source IP: %s port: %u, Target IP: %s port: %u.\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]), argv[3], atoi(argv[4]));


    // include a timestamp
    memset(data, ' ', sizeof(data));
    the_time = htonl(time(NULL));
    memcpy(data, &the_time, sizeof(the_time));

    //Compute UDP checksum
    CreatePseudoHeaderAndComputeUdpChecksum(udp_header, ip_header, (unsigned char*)data);

    for (ix = 0; ix < 1000000; ++ix)
    {

      //Copy IP header, UDP header, and data to the packet buffer.
      memcpy(buffer, ip_header, sizeof(struct ip));
      memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ip), udp_header, 8 /*sizeof(struct udphdr)*/);
      memcpy(buffer + sizeof(struct ip) + 8, data, DATA_SIZE);

    // length must include header sizes
    #if 0
      if(sendto(sd, buffer, 20/*ip_header->ip_len*/, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&to_addr, sizeof(to_addr)) < 0)
    #else
      if(sendto(sd, buffer, sizeof(struct ip) + sizeof(struct udphdr) + DATA_SIZE, 0, 
            (struct sockaddr *)&to_addr, sizeof(to_addr)) < 0)
    #endif
      {
    perror("sendto() error");
    break;
      }
      else
      {
          printf("sendto() is OK.\n");
      }
      sleep(1);
    } // loop
    free(ip_header);
    free(udp_header);
    close(sd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Multicast with RAW Socket in C on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864844/sending-multicast-with-raw-socket-in-c-on-linux)